# Django Rest Framework + Postman + JSON parse error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman, jsonparser

I created a Django Api. I used rest_framework.generics.CreateAPIView to post. It works well in default browser. But When i use Postman it throws a error.

**`views.py`**

```
class AuthorCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
  queryset = Author.objects.all()
  serializer_class = AuthorCreateUpdateSerializer
```

**`serializers.py`**

```
class AuthorCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
  model = Author
  fields = [
    'name',
    'biography',
  ]
```

**Error** : `"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"`

[image: Postman view]

Comment: In your postman choose `raw` instead of `form-data` and then choose `Json(application/json)` as your input type and check if it works

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is it possible to post data by form-data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you used `form-data` as your input, you should use `application/json` instead.

however you can fix your project's settings file to accept form-data too. You need to add `FormParser` to your `DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES` in your project's `settings.py`. It should look like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried it before. it creates problem to generate JWT token. It throws `"detail": "Unsupported media type \"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary73BA8CafGxDW9ARJ\" in request."`

Comment: are you sending files in that request?

Comment: No, i sent username and password by `form-data`

Comment: Could you send a screenshot of that request and its error?

Comment: What library are you using to create JWT tokens? It seems that it only accepts Json inputs.

Comment: `from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token`

Comment: The image shows that you have something in your `headers` in postman. What is it? Is it content-type?

Comment: No it's authorization